# How can i auto remove the reaction if the other one is clicked? discord rewrite

Tags: python, url-rewriting, discord

How can i auto remove the reaction if the other one is clicked? discord rewrite.
i need to make a suggest command with upvotes and downvotes but I need to auto remove if you want to click both it will remove the one you place before!

```
@client.command()
async def suggest(ctx, *, text):
    usern = ctx.message.author
    usern = str(usern)
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title = f"Suggestion from {usern}",
        description = text,
        colour = discord.Colour.green()
    )
    channel = client.get_channel(706785347840901131)
    message = await channel.send(embed=embed)
    emoji = "✅"
    emoji2 = '❌'
    await message.add_reaction(emoji)
    await message.add_reaction(emoji2)
```